# Read names and values with class and constructor

Tags: c#, oop, io

I want read how many students are in school,and read these students name and grades one by one with using class and constructor. Then, show a grade table of school.

For example school has 5 student and i type

- "John" "85"
- "Michael" "59"
- "Robert" "64"
- "Jane" "100"
- "Tony" "42"

then I want program will show me this table

- 0-39:
- 40-69:***
- 70-89:*
- 90-100:*

Here is the little code and design. (That is not an exam question or assignment, i am very new in C# and just trying solve some problems.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace csharcpconsole
{
   
    class Program
    {
        class Student
        {
            public string name;
            public int grade;

            public Student(string studentname, int studentgrade)
            {
                name = studentname;
                grade = studentgrade;
            }

        }

        static void Main ()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("How many student you will add?");
            int studentcount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            for(int i=0;i<studentcount;i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Please enter the {i + 1}'th student name.");
               Student  st = new Student (Console.ReadLine())

                Console.WriteLine($"Please enter the {i + 1}'th student name and grade.");
                Student st = new Student int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())
            }


        }

       

       
    }
}
```

Comment: And what exactly is the problem here? What output do you *expect*?

Comment: Does your code work?  If not, what doesn't work?  Are you having some sort of problem?  If so, what?  It looks like you wrote the first few lines and gave up.  Consider keeping the entered data in a `List<Student>`.  Also consider using `int.TryParse` instead of `int.Parse` (that way your program won't blow up on an invalid entry.  Also, rather than asking how many students up front, just keep asking until someone enters an empty string as the student name

Answer (score 0):

1. I would change your Student class to use auto properties
2. Use a `List<T>` to store each new Student created
3. Print to console and use `Linq` to get Count of Students in grade range

   ```
   public class Student
   {
       public string Name { get; set;} //auto property
       public int Grade { get; set; } //auto property
   }

   static void Main ()
   {
       Console.WriteLine("How many student will you add?");
       string consoleInput = Console.ReadLine();
       //int for out parameter of int.TryParse()
       int outInt = default(int); //Or in C# 9 - int outInt = default;
       int studentcount = Int32.TryParse(consoleInput, out outInt) ? 
                            outInt : 0; // Or throw an exception??
       //initialize a List<T> of Student type
       List<Student> students = new List<Student>(studentcount);

       for(int i=0;i<studentcount;i++)
       {               
          Console.WriteLine($"Please enter the {i + 1}'th student name.");
          Student st = new Student { Name = Console.ReadLine() };

          Console.WriteLine($"Please enter the {i + 1}'th student name and grade.");
          //You don't need to create another Student, use the one from above
          //re-use the string from above
          consoleInput = Console.ReadLine();
          st.Grade = Int32.TryParse(consoleInput, out outInt) ? 
                         outInt : 0; //Or throw exception??

          //Add your student to the list
          students.Add(st);
       }

       //Print the result to the console
       if(students.Count > 0)
       {
           //Get students 0-39
           int number = students.Where(z => z.Grade < 40).Count();
           Console.WriteLine("0-39: " + ReturnAsteriks(number));
           //students 40-69
           number = students.Where(z => z.Grade >= 40 && z.Grade < 70).Count();
           Console.WriteLine("40-69: " + ReturnAsteriks(number));
           //students 70-89
           number = students.Where(z => z.Grade >= 70 && z.Grade < 90).Count();
           Console.WriteLine("70-89: " + ReturnAsteriks(number));
           //students 90-100
           number = students.Where(z => z.Grade >= 90).Count();
           Console.WriteLine("90-100: " + ReturnAsteriks(number));
       }
   }

   //Private method to build the number of asteriks
   //Takes an int and returns a string of asteriks
   private string ReturnAsteriks(int numOfAsteriks)
   {
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
       for(int z = 0; z < numOfAsteriks; z++)
       {
           sb.Append("*");
       }

       return sb.ToString();
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much ! I didn't reach the Linq part in C# lessons yet but i will study your code.

Comment: @BerkeTabak You're welcome. Let me know if you have any questions. Hope this helps.